# I want to delete a specified row in an html table where a class cannot be added

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the dokan mutivendor plug-in in the wordpress plug-in.
When I created a child theme and edited the layout, I found a part that cannot be edited. Even if you comment out the relevant part of the layout, it cannot be hidden.
Therefore, it is not possible to attach a class to a specific table row.
At present, the solution is trying to edit the layout with javascript.
As editing contents, I want to delete lines 3, 5, and 6 in the code.
Sorry for the poor explanation, thank you.

```
<table class="content">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lines"? 3, 5, and 6 are in table cells. If you remove those cells, the rows will be jagged because they won't have a consistent number of cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand your question so please clarify if this is not your requested answer.

You could use the css selector `:nth-child(x)` to select the correct cells that need to disappear. Then you can use `display: none;` to hide these cells.

If you don't want other cells to jump in weird places you could use `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;`.

```css
table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3), table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2), table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3){
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table> 
 <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am glad to inform you that the problem is now solved.

Comment: Hi Tkeita, if this was due to this answer please check this as correct. Otherwise feel free to post your own answer to your question.

Comment: `table.content> tbody> tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(3),table.wc-metabox-content > tbody> tr:nth-child(2)>td:nth-child(3) ,table.wc-metabox-content > tbody> tr:nth-child(2)>td:nth-child(2){
    display: none;
}`  This is the answer I wanted

Comment: @TKeita it seems like my answer was the correct answer for your given problem (with the information given). Please click the arrow to the left to my answer to clarify to other users that this was the correct answer for your question. As a bonus this will reward us both with reputation for adding a correct solution for this website!